# How to fix Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '****'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular for frontend for the first time.

In my Angular app in the **user-profile.component.html** there is an edit button that has a designated route for it in the **app-routing.module.ts** file.

Here is my **user-profile.component.html**

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner>
<mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf="posts.length > 0 && !isLoading">
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ post.title }}
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div class="post-image">
      <img [src]="post.imagePath" [alt]="post.title">
    </div>
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    <mat-action-row *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated && userId === post.creator">
      <button mat-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['userProfileEdit', post.id]">EDIT</button>
      <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="onDelete(post.id)">DELETE</button>
    </mat-action-row>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<mat-paginator [length]="totalPosts" [pageSize]="postsPerPage" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" (page)="onPageChanged($event)" *ngIf="posts.length > 0"></mat-paginator>
<p class="info-text mat-body-1" *ngIf="posts.length <= 0 && !isLoading">No posts Yet</p>
```

Here in line 12 there is that `routerLink`, `[routerLink]="['userProfileEdit', post.id]"`

Which points to this route in **app-routing.module.ts** given below,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PostListComponent } from './posts/post-list/post-list.component';
import { PostCreateComponent } from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './auth/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './auth/signup/signup.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth-guard';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile/user-profile.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: PostListComponent },
  {path: 'create', component: PostCreateComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  {path: 'edit/:postId', component: PostCreateComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
  {path: 'userProfile', component: UserProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'userProfileEdit/:postId', component: PostCreateComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here in line 17, there is that designated route `{path: 'userProfileEdit/:postId', component: PostCreateComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}` that should correspond.

I fixed the syntax error that I had in this line as I searched for the similar issues in SO `[routerLink]="['userProfileEdit', post.id]"`. But still it did not work.

To mention, All other routes in that **app-routing.module.ts** work perfectly in all other parts of my app, no issues.

Here is a screenshot of the error in the console log.

[image]

Just expecting some little clue. Thank you.

Comment: try swapping the position of the userProfileEdit/:postId and userProfile.  I think order is important, going from most specific to least specific route

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried what you said but unfortunately did not work.

Comment: @RatnadeepChakraborty replace this `[routerLink]="['userProfileEdit', post.id]"` with this `[routerLink]="['/userProfileEdit', post.id]"`

Comment: @AbdulBasil Thank you very much sir ! It worked. But can you just tell me why was not it working the other way as all others are working without that slash ? Just to know for future purpose.

Comment: @RatnadeepChakraborty please check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace this

```
 [routerLink]="['userProfileEdit', post.id]
```

with this

```
[routerLink]="['/userProfileEdit', post.id]"
```

**Edit**

If you add slash `/` to `routerLink` like `[routerLink]="['/userProfileEdit']`, it means go to route with base url like `localhost/userProfileEdit`. And if you add route without slash `/` like `[routerLink]="['userProfileEdit']`, it will append `userProfileEdit` to the existing url already in address bar.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.